# Cordova IOS platform update disables swipe-to-go-back feature in Ionic

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I updated IOS platform of my Ionic project from 3.9.2 to 4.2.1. After the update, swipe-to-go-back feature is disabled. I don't disable swipe-to-go-back anywhere. I also tried to correct it by adding `$ionicConfigProvider.views.swipeBackEnabled(true)` line to app.js, but it didn't work. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Another way of enabling is by adding the following code on the views:

`<ion-view can-swipe-back="true"></ion-view>`